# Loading own dags in Airflow

Tags: airflow

When running Airflow server for the first time after installation, in the DAG list, there is already some dags, such as "example_dash_operator", "example_branch_labels", etc.

Airflow doc says that, to create our own DAGs, we should put in a `dags` folder, which should be in this location `AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow/dags/` (`AIRFLOW_HOME` is the folder where I install Airflow). I put a sample `dag1.py` in this folder. But after re-logging in into `localhost:8080`, I still see only the standard list of DAGS after installation. I don't see `dag1.py`. I have both the server and the scheduler running with :

```
airflow webserver --port 8080
```

```
airflow scheduler
```

The full folder structure is as following:

```
\AIRFLOW_HOME\
      airflow\
           airflow-webserver.pid
           airflow.db
           logs\
           airflow.cfg
           dags\
               dag1.py
           webserver_config.py
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992997/dag-not-visible-in-web-ui) here advised to run `airflow dags list` first. `dag1.py` does not appear on the list when I run that command. And, after running that, restarting the server and scheduler, the web UI still does not list `dag1.py`

in `airflow.cfg`, I have this line defining the `dags` folder:

```
dags_folder = /xxxxxx/airflow/dags
```

where the `xxxxxx` is the absolute path of `AIRFLOW_HOME`.

The content of `dag1.py` is code copied from a tutorial in [this Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IH1-0hwFZRQ). So I think it is a valid dag.

What am I missing?

Comment: Example DAGs are coming from [load_examples](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#load-examples) setting. Set to false if you only want your own dags loaded from dags folder.

Answer (score 0):

The `AIRFLOW_HOME` is NOT where you install airflow. The AIRFLOW_HOME is where you aither:

- have `AIRFLOW_HONE` environment point to
- or if you have no AIRFLOW_HOME variable defined when you run airflow, it defaults to "${HOME}/airflow"

See:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-config.html?highlight=airflow_home

> The first time you run Airflow, it will create a file called airflow.cfg in your $AIRFLOW_HOME directory (~/airflow by default). This file contains Airflow's configuration and you can edit it to change any of the settings. You can also set options with environment variables by using this format: AIRFLOW__{SECTION}__{KEY} (note the double underscores).

Comment: I edited my question to include where AIRFLOW_HOME is. It is my virtual environment locaition where the ```airflow\``` folder is created. If this is the case, what am I doing wrong with the ```dags``` folder?

Comment: What's your dag1.py content ? You need it importable, and it needs to create some DAGs when parsed.