# Apache airflow doens't display the DAG

Tags: airflow

I'm facing some issues trying to set up a basic DAG file inside the Airflow (but also I have other two files).

I'm using the LocalExecutor through the Ubuntu and saved my files at "C:\Users\tdamasce\Documents\workspace" with the dag and log file inside it.

My script is

```
# step 1 - libraries

from email.policy import default
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

# step 2 

default_args = {
    'ownwer': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'retries':0
}

# step 3

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='DAG-1',
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5)
)

# step 4

start = DummyOperator(
    task_id='start',
    dag=dag
)

end = DummyOperator(
    task_id='end',
    dag=dag
)
```

My DAG stays like that:

[image]

Please, let me know if any add info is needed

Comment: Are you using standalone Airflow or with Docker ? ,Where are you placing the Dag files ?

Comment: Did you try to restart the server  ` systemctl restart airflow-webserver `

Comment: PLease see if these links helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992997/dag-not-visible-in-web-ui ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684434/airflow-new-dag-is-not-found-by-webserver

Comment: thanks a lot @VineeshVijayan, I'll take a look. I update the text. I'm doing Standalone airflow using Ubuntu and saved the files on the "Documents folder"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your updated Question , I can see that you place the DAgs under a directory

> "C:\Users\tdamasce\Documents\workspace" with the dag and log file
> inside it.

you need to add dags  to dags_folder (specified in airflow.cfg. By default it's $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags subfolder). See if your AIRFLOW_HOME variable and you should found a dag folder there.

you can also check `airflow list_dags`   - this will list out all the dags,

Still you are not able to get that in the UI , then restart the servers.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, I ran "airflow dags list" and says that "no data found", I'll double check again the AIRFLOW_HOME to check the folders

Comment: related to the dags_folder path it should be "C:/Users/tdamasce/Documents/workspace/dags", right?

Comment: if your AIRFLOW_HOME is :/Users/tdamasce/Documents/workspace , then yes, you can look into your airflow.config to see details

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked with the {AIRFLOW_HOME}, but I had to change to "/home/tayzer/workspace, now is working properly